# Should DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST_SIZE be smaller than the respective partition size?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

Is it OK to set the DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST_SIZE to be equal to a drive partition that is dedicated for this purpose?

That is, if I use a partition of 10GB, is it ok to set the DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST_SIZE to be equal to 10GB?

Or is there a chance that errors will occur due to insufficient space in the drive, and I should use a smaller value?

Edit (more details):

My setup has the following parameters:

```
db_recovery_file_dest            string  /oracle/fra
db_recovery_file_dest_size       big integer 10G
```

Comment: Post the output of `df -B1 /oracle/fra`.

Comment: the actual partition is 345G and the output for 1B-blocks is 370104938496 (I used 10G in the question to keep it simple)

Comment: it's clear from your answer that it there should be 345*1024*1024*1024 = 370440929280 bytes available so I guess 344G would be better! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

10 GB as 10240 `MiB`?

10 GB as 10000 `MB`?

Is it 10 GB because of the rounding, but the actual size is 10227 `MiB`? Or 10213 `MiB`?

Setting `db_recovery_file_dest_size` to 10G means the size of FRA will be 10*1024*1024*1024 = 10737418240 bytes. As long as that is less than or equal to the available space in the filesystem (not partition!), it should be fine.

I usually set `db_recovery_file_dest_size` a bit smaller than the amount of free space in the filesystem or ASM diskgroup if I get a dedicated filesystem or diskgroup for it.

Comment: thanks a lot, I added some details, can you please clarify if the size of the partition that is set with `db_recovery_file_dest matters` (or is it the whole filesystem indeed?). Also you can see how `10G` is set. thanks again!